# Why image don't fill width

Tags: android, imageview, android-layout

I have the following in my main.xml the image marker does not fill the width of the device?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/ImageView01" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"        
    android:src="@drawable/marker">
</ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have your ImageView's height set to `wrap_content`. This means the ImageView will only take as much space as is needed by the image you select. If you want it to take the entire screen, just change your layout_height to `fill_parent`.

You'll also want to select an ImageView `scaleType` with `android:scaleType=""`.

Comment: I did have the width set to fill_parent above?I will check into the scaleType. Just now it worked.This emulator is buggy as hell,half the time it works half the time it don't.

Comment: Er, I meant height, sorry. I'll edit that in. Change your ImageView's height.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

or check out

```
image_view_1.xml
```

in the Android APIDemos.

It should be of help.

Comment: It worked when I tested it just now.Seems the emulator is buggy as can be!