# ImageView doesn't fill entire width

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm developing an Android 2.2 application for multiple devices and I have a problem with an image.

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/layout_empty"
            android:src="@drawable/faqs" />

    </ScrollView>
```

And this is what I see on my tablet device:

[image]

It looks perfect on my HTC Desire.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add `android:scaleType="fitXY"` to your ImageView

Comment: Excellent. Now, just in order to understand, wouldn't be the function of this line?
`android:layout_width="match_parent"`

Comment: But it didn't keep aspect ratio. Even with android:adjustViewBounds="true" parameter!

Answer (score 1):

See the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236642/why-image-dont-fill-width). Need to set the layout_height of the image view to fill_parent